# (webdriver) is it possible to terminate IEDriverServer process without terminating the IE browser?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

When running a webdriver test on IE,  can i terminate the terminate IEDriverServer process but leave the browser open  [or is it contradictory and closing the IEDriverServer is synonymous with closing the browser?]

There reason for asking - i want to  continue coding  from where the webdriver  test I launch but clear the memory from the selenium left off, 
so taking a screenshot is no good, as i need to check the next menu items, fields and such.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My understanding on your question is :- You want to take control of the browser after selenium completes its actions. If my understanding is correct, you can achieve this by not quitting the driver at end of your tests.

So far I have tried, invoked browser will be closed if we kill IEdriverServer exe.

You can give it a try to understand it yourself. Java code to kill IEdriverserver process is mentioned below.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(KILL + "IEDriverServer.exe");
```